# Does the data in mongodb provisioned in EC2 gets replicated while Autoscaling?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

To deploy a server in Amazon Ec2, I wish to have the mongodb master database in an Ec2 instance itself and at an average I would be having around 5-6 Ec2 instances running in parallel which are scaled by amazon auto-scaling group.

As database is updated frequently and all instances are under Elastic load balancer,it is hard to predict which users data is in which database of Ec2. By following this approach, am i assured of data consistency in mongodb across the instances while scaling up and down ? If it is not the good approach please suggest alternate ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Amazon autoscaling, new EC2 instances will be created from a root AMI image (for example, with an empty database).

As data is added to your database, that data is not synced back to the AMI image. So when a second EC2 instance is launched due to a scaling event, that new EC2 instance will have it's own blank database, because it will be based on the same root AMI image (with the blank database).

The two databases will not know about each other and no syncing will occur. Also, at any time, any of the EC2 instances may be deleted due to a scale-down event. So any data on that instance may be lost.

Separate your web layer from the database layer: use autoscaling to scale your web layer, but don't use autoscaling for your data layer.

MongoDB has it's own form of clustering for load balancing and high-availability. Use it rather than rolling your own using autoscaling.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a standard practice to couple your web server with the database server. Here is what I would suggest.

Implement load balancing on your web servers as well as your mongo db instances so for the sake of argument, you will have 4 web and 4 mongo db servers.

For implementing load balancing on your mongo db servers, it is up to you if you wish to go with a master-slave tier where each mongo db server is a master as well as a slave(so that all instances have data synced) or you can look into sharding.

Comment: did you mean amazon automatically syncs the data on mongodb across multiple ec2-instances?

Comment: No, there is no automatic syncing. You have to do this yourself.

Comment: thank you @MattHouser. then its obvious that my approach is not correct. I have to separate the database from the ec2 instance. I might need to use some mongodb and aws integration kind of services.